# Baker's Math Formula System - Why Isn't the Flour Mass in Corn Bread Formula 100%?

Tags: bread, baker-percentage

I am currently in the middle of a challenge to bake every formula in the [Bread Baker's Apprentice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1580082688) book (BBA). This book describes a principal called the [Baker's Math Formula System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker_percentage) where all ingredients are compared to the total flour weight in the formula as a ratio. (BBA referes to recipes as formulas.) By definition (or so I thought), the ratio for the total flour weight in a given formula is always supposed to be 100%.

The author includes this analysis for each formula in the book.  Just last night, I looked at the Baker's Percentage for the Corn Bread formula in more detail and found that the ratio listed for the flour is actually 51.1%.  How could this be if the total flour weight is supposed to be 100%? Would this have anything to do with the fact that this is a chemically leavened bread?

[image]

Comment: thats my least favorite recipe in BBA

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I decided to try to e-mail my question to the author, Peter Reinhart.  As it turns out, there is a typo in the book!

> "Together, the flour and cornmeal should equal 100%. It's the flour %
>   that's listed wrong, not the cornmeal, because the total is 14 oz and
>   the flour is listed as 8 oz. If you divide 8 by 14 you get 57.1%,
>   which means the cornmeal is correctly listed at 42.9%  So change the
>   flour percent -- that's a typo I can see can easily happen since 1 and
>   7 are kind of similar looking and easily overlooked."

Comment: Awesome! Nice job emailing him.

Answer (score 2):

I believe its expressed as a percentages of the all purpose flour, the cornmeal, and the chemical leavening.  I'm not sure why the leavening appears to be included, but for the cornmeal and the flour - they're both elements that would provide the same role as flour in a traditional yeast recipe.

The cornmeal and flour together seems to be somewhat common as I found at [least one more](https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/bprecipes.html) that expresses them together for 100.

Either way, if it makes it easier you can always scale all the numbers up so that the flour equals 100.

Comment: I agree those components add up to 100% (if you round up 99.76). It would make sense to me if the cornmeal and the flour equaled 100% but including the leavening doesn't make sense to me based on the definition.